# SQL Query in VBA runs EPICALLY slow

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access

This may be a long shot, but I've exhausted my options at this point. The following SQL query is written into my Access VBA

```
SELECT 
    TBLactionstaken.RecordNumber, 
    TBLactionstaken.ActionTakenID,     
    TBLactionstaken.ReasonID,     
    TBLactionstaken.LetterAddress,     
    TBLactionstaken.ProcessedDate,     
    TBLactionstaken.ProcessedBy,     
    TBLparticipants.PartLName,     
    TBLactionstaken.LetterType,     
    TBLactionstaken.LetterTo,     
    TBLactionstaken.ActionBy,     
    TBLactionstaken.MANHType,     
    TBLactionstaken.ActionDate,     
    TBLactionstaken.ActionStatus 
FROM 
    TBLparticipants     
INNER JOIN 
    TBLactionstaken ON TBLparticipants.RecordNumber = TBLactionstaken.RecordNumber 
WHERE 
    TBLactionstaken.ActionDate BETWEEN #9/15/2021# AND #9/22/2021# 
    AND TBLactionstaken.ActionID = 2 
    AND TBLactionstaken.Processed IS NULL
    AND TBLactionstaken.DeleteDate IS NULL
    AND TBLactionstaken.ActionStatus = 'Pending' 
ORDER BY 
    TBLactionstaken.ReasonID, TBLparticipants.PartLName;
```

Currently, it takes a good 15 minutes to run. The tables its pulling from - `Participant` and `ActionsTaken` -  are quite large, however, it can pull a less complicated one off these tables in less than a second.

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Have you tried running the query directly on the database? By doing so, you can determine if it is the query that is epically slow or if there is a problem in Access/VBA code. If the query is slow when you run it directly on the database you need to do some optimizing there, otherwise take a look at the VBA code.

Comment: If you compare that slow query to one of the fast queries, does the slow query include unindexed fields in the `FROM`, `WHERE`, or `ORDER BY` clauses which are not included in the corresponding clauses of the fast query?

Comment: @bjorsig I have and same result, I've compacted and repaired this thing a million times. I also have most of my larger tables on a separate back end

Comment: @HansUp so it does include unindexed fields in the slow query but the fast one has no indexes.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused by "the fast one has no indexes".  Putting that aside, I suggest you start with a simple version of your query --- just the `JOIN`, but no `WHERE` or `ORDER BY`.  In that situation, your join field `RecordNumber` should be indexed in both tables.  If that performs fast, add the first constraint from your `WHERE` clause; you should have `ActionDate` indexed for that.  Keep on adding parts back piece by piece until you pinpoint the one which makes the query too slow.

Comment: @HansUp I'm setting that up now to see what happens, should the indexes for the recordnumber be primary keys in both or either table?

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether they're primary as long as they're indexed.

Comment: It doesn't say which type of RDBMS you are using, but most or all them some way of getting to see the query plan. Oracle and PostgreSQL have the keyword EXPLAIN and then you can see which part of the query is the most time consuming. MS SQL Studio has a tab, query plan or something like that. Try that, see what is using up the resources and try to speed up, perhaps dropping or creating index to match your faster table. In most servers you can specify to skip using certain index or force it.

Comment: Create an actual query in Access (you can delete it later) and then go to Database Tools >> Analyze Performance >> Queries and select the query. Access will tell you if any critical indexes are missing and add them for you.